# gmail macro to select only "to" messages in priority inbox (mutt)

Tags: linux, email, gmail, mutt

I have this line in `~/.muttrc`:

```
macro index tp "<change-folder>[Gmail]/Important<enter>" "Go to priority inbox"
```

which successfully restricts what `mutt` grabs to only Gmail's priority inbox.

But, it grabs messages `From` me as well as messages `To` me. That's not what I want: I want to see only *priority* messages that are *to* me.

I can think of two ways to fix this annoyance:

1. Use `mutt`'s built-in filters after typing <kbd>t</kbd>,<kbd>p</kbd> to remove the messages `From` me.
2. Improve the `macro index` line above. Maybe gmail accepts a code that will further delimit what it's grabbing. (In the web interface's search bar I know it would be `-from:my.address@gmail.com`. But I'm not sure how to work that into `[Gmail]/Important`.)

I've googled around but can't find exactly these types of answers. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close.  All you need to add to your macro is a limit; using mutt directly you'd press “l” then enter “~p” (you can see the full list of patterns [in the mutt documentation](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#ss4.2)).  So in a macro you would get something like:

```
macro index tp "<change-folder>[Gmail]/Important<enter><limit>~p<enter>" "Go to priority inbox"
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the quick response! It worked.